# How do you check if an object is a regular expression across V8 contexts?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, v8

I recently [discovered](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1557) that when you use the literal regular expression syntax in one V8 context, `instanceof RegExp` returns false even if you share the global `RegExp` object between contexts.

```
var Contextify = require('contextify');
var ctx = Contextify({ RegExp:RegExp, app: anExpressApp });

// When you create a new route, Express checks if the argument is an
// `instanceof RegExp`, and assumes it is a string if not.

ctx.run("
    app.get(new RegExp('...'), function() { ... }); // works because we share the `RegExp` global between contexts
    app.get(/.../, function() { ... }); // does not work
");
```

How do you reliably check if an object is a `RegExp` cross-context?

Comment: What does `Object.prototype.toString.call(theRegExp)` return?

Comment: Also using `instanceof` a basic type has been a mistake for a long time - in the browser context, inter-iframe objects cause the same problem, and all the JavaScript libraries had to figure this out years ago. Usually, duck typing is the most straightforward solution, but it depends on your application I guess.

Comment: @Pointy: Looks like you're on to something with `toString` -- it returns `[object RegExp]` in both contexts.

Comment: does /yourregex/.constructor.prototype === RegExp.prototype

Comment: @jermel: No, for the same reason that `instanceof` returns false: the `RegExp` of a separate [context](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#contexts) is an entirely different `RegExp`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745427/how-do-you-check-if-an-object-is-a-regular-expression-across-v8-contexts#comment22374244_15745427) gives us the most reliable route.

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(regExp) == '[object RegExp]') ...
```

This relies on the [specified behavior of `toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2), which is to return the JavaScript internal [*[[Class]]*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) property of the object (plus `"[object "` and `"]"`).

Since this is simple string comparison, it works across contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will confirm you have a RegEx or something pretending to be a RegEx.

```
function regExLike(o) {
   return typeof o==='object' && 
          typeof o.global==='boolean' && 
          typeof o.test==='function' ;
}
```